# NExpectation not up to expectations with Boole or Conditioned

Tags: probability-or-statistics, numerics, precision-and-accuracy, conditional

*Context*

I am interested in computing numerically the number of extrema at a given threshold for random fields. These numbers are expectations of MultinormalDistributions.

*Problem*

This integral should give the differential number of maxima of a scale invariant Gaussian random field ($\gamma=0$ i.e.  white noise) at threshold zero.

```
NExpectation[(-(x*y) + z^2)*Boole[x*y - z^2 <= 0], 
{x, z, y} \[Distributed] 
MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{3/8, 0, 1/8}, {0, 1/8, 0}, {1/8, 0, 3/8}}]]
```

Its value should be `1/4/Sqrt[3]= 0.144338` whereas Mathematica returns 0.138245 which is wrong by a factor of 5 %.

Strangely enough if I split the integral in two as

```
NExpectation[(-(x*y) + z^2)*Boole[x + y >= 0 && x*y - z^2 <= 0], 
 {x, z, y} \[Distributed] 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0},{{3/8, 0, 1/8}, {0, 1/8, 0}, {1/8, 0, 3/8}}]] +
NExpectation[(-(x*y) + z^2)*Boole[x + y <= 0 && x*y - z^2 <= 0], 
  {x, z, y} \[Distributed] 
MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{3/8, 0, 1/8}, {0, 1/8, 0}, {1/8, 0, 3/8}}]]
```

Mathematica returns the correct answer to 5 digits.

I understand integrating numerically Boole is likely to cause problems but I am nonetheless surprised by the poor result.

On a related topic

```
 NExpectation[-(x*y) + z^2 \[Conditioned] (x*y - z^2 < 0), 
 {x, z, y} \[Distributed] 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{3/8, 0, 1/8}, {0, 1/8, 0}, {1/8, 0, 3/8}}]]
```

seems to take a while before returning unevaluated (even though it should probably be the correct way to proceed?).

**Questions**

> 1. Why is the first method doing so poorly?
> 2. Why is the second method failing altogether?
> 3. Any guidance on how to tell NExpectation to be "smart" about the Boole condition?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Did you read http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numerical integration in Mma is a big topic. 
I suggest reading at least [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html).

The following gives the correct answer:

```
NExpectation[(-(x*y) + z^2) Boole[x*y - z^2 <= 0], {x, z, y} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{3/8, 0, 1/8}, {0, 1/8, 0}, {1/8, 0, 3/8}}], 
     Method -> {"NIntegrate", {Exclusions -> True}}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will look at your link. Do you happen to know why the Conditioned formulation fails altogether?